# jQuery - how to extract one class starting with into a variable

Tags: jquery, class, variables, jquery-selectors, startswith

I'm working with a dynamically created list of elements, some of which are associated into sets with a class or 'Set1, Set2, etc. The elements have multiple classes, in various assigned orders but each has only one class starting with 'Set...', such as...

```
<div class="SharedClass anotherClass Set2 yetAnotherClass">SomethingA</div>
<div class="SharedClass anotherClass Set2 yetAnotherClass">SomethingB</div>
<div class="someClass SharedClass Set3 yetAnotherClass">SomethingC</div>
```

So, how can I extract the specific class starting with 'Set' from into a variable 'clickedSet' to seed this click function to show only the members of the current clicked set?

```
$('.SharedClass').click(function(){

    var clickedSet = $(this). //Get the specific classname starting with 'Set...'

    $(':not("clickedSet")').hide();
    $('.clickedSet').show();
});
```

Any ideas gratefully received.
Best,
Keith..

Answer (score 0):

may be something like:

```
    $("[class^=Set]").click(function(){
    //whatever you want to process 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but this select 'class starting with set...' will include all elements of Set 2 AND Set3 not just the clicked one. My challenge is how to extract the specific 'class staring with Set...' from the clicked element to define the filter - I'm happy that I can apply it once available.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PU3Tk/)

```
$('.SharedClass').click(function () {
    var classList = this.className.split(/\s+/),
        clickedSet;
    for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
        if (classList[i].indexOf('Set') === 0) {
            clickedSet = classList[i];           
            break;
        }
    }
    $('.'+clickedSet).show();
});
```